# Spring transactional readOnly and isolation levels

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I read about the propagation and isolation in the spring/hibernate. 
I have one specific method where we have

```
0. @Transactional (the default spring annotation)
1. read several rows
2. some business logic
3. read (from other table using some data from the first read)
```

That looks a bit unsafe to me. What if someone else deletes a row during step 2.
I think that I should change the method annotation to

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

Is that a valid fix for my specific case? (the task is to fix transactional annotations causing some problems with the system and change as few other lines of code as possible)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your case, you have some method, which do several reading from database.

So, if your method just read from DB, so you just need to have annotation like: `@Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`

Because in fact you just read from database.

But if your method provide both access to database read & write - the best way is to separate it to two methods, and one of them would be readOnly.

Comment: yes but it is not "just" as the SERIALIZABLE is the heaviest isolation. do we really need it in my case? maybe yes - 99% sure.

Comment: @saferJo sorry, i corrected my answer and remove SERIALIZABLE, it  was just misspelling

Comment: what if during the business logic someone deletes something from the first table and commits.

Comment: @saferJo so, it depends on project...
Read Uncommitted: Allows dirty reads
Read Committed: Does not allow dirty reads
Repeatable Read: If a row is read twice in the same transaciton, result will always be the same
Serializable: Performs all transactions in a sequence

here is the list of isolations

Comment: so in my case should be serializable because the second read will rely that something in the table is not deleted meanwhile maybe...

Comment: @saferJo so yes, it is. And i thhink it answered complete now :)

Comment: @saferJo and answer is reverted to begining state

Answer (score 1):

It depend what you mean by unsafe, what you business logic you write, in your example you only performing a read operations while the serializable is recommended in quick read/write operations, also in your case if something being updated in first table a serializable transaction will operates as nothing being executed- like a frozen environment ,
As long as others transactions insert data it will be invisible for you, hence at end the result of your second read could be wrong

As they mention on oracle as example :

> Database inconsistencies can result unless such application-level consistency checks are coded with this in mind, even when using serializable transactions.

Also when you  used serializable here you must be aware of **cannot serialize access**  exception that can occur inside your code (other class) while you try to update the same table, which could be tricky

Another approach to solve that is use Read Committed Isolation and while you re-implementing the second read keep in mind representing  the real state of database, i mean if  other rows receive update and  **commit** they must be taking into consideration using data used in first read, without a real example of your method i can't give you full working example.